# Cannot Locate to review text in booking.com by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm practicing to get reviews from booking.com where all reviews were hidden in the side bar.  I just pick one hotel and see there were 93 reviews so I need to loop for multiple pages on that side bar.  My code to work on switch_to_window cannot locate to those reviews even I check the tags were matched in Chrome developer console.  May I have your suggestions what should I do?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./driver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://booking.com")

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class*='sb-searchbox__input']").send_keys("Eden The Residence at The Sea")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Eden The Residence at The Sea')]").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='room_info_heading'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)** instead of time.sleep() to wait for element be loaded.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(3)
// Add this line to show reviews
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#show_reviews_tab').click() 
// Use WebDriverWait to wait element be visibility
room_info = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='room_info_heading']"))) 
print(room_info.text)
```

Output:

```
Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub
```

And you can use loop as below:

```
room_info_list = []
while True:
    // visibility_of_all_element's'_located
    room_info_eles = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='room_info_heading']")))
    room_info = [room_info_eles[i].text for i in range(0, len(room_info_eles))]
    print(room_info)
    room_info_list.extend(room_info)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='pagenext']"))).click()
    except Exception:  // If next button cannot be click, break loop
        break

print(room_info_list)
```

Output:

```
['Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Three-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop Lounge with Tub', 'Stayed in: Beachside Five-Bedroom Villa with Private Pool and Rooftop with Tub']
```